# WPF: Tree view by parsing string

Tags: wpf, tree

Why is my tree displaying only up to 2 levels? For example, `NetworkControl.AddressData.MessageOriginatorID.Value` shows only `NetworkControl` as root and `AddressData` as a child but `AddressData` doesn't show `MessageOriginatorID.Value` as a child.

Input data:

```
       public List<TreeModel> GetRequestTreeNodes()
        {

        string[] nodes = {"NetworkControl.AlternateIndexText.Value",
                             "NetworkControl.AddressData.DestinationID",
                             "NetworkControl.AddressData.MessageOriginatorID.Value",
                             "NetworkControl.AddressData.TransactionOriginatorID.Value",
                             "NetworkControl.AddressData.MessageOriginatorID.Value",
                             "VehicleIdentification.IdentificationID.Value",
                             "VehicleSummary.VehicleIdentification.IdentificationID.Value",
                             "TitleSummary.TitleIdentification.IdentificationID.Value",
                             "TitleSummary.JurisdictionTitlingKeyText.Value",
                             "VehicleSummary.VehicleIdentification.IdentificationID.Value",
                              };

        List<TreeModel> nodeList = BuildTree(nodes);

        return nodeList;

    }
```

Parser method:

```
      public List<TreeModel> BuildTree(IEnumerable<string> strings)
    {
        return (
          from s in strings
          let split = s.Split('.')
          group s by s.Split('.')[0] into g
          select new TreeModel
          {
              Name = g.Key,
              Children = BuildTree(
                from s in g
                where s.Length > g.Key.Length + 1
                select s.Substring(g.Key.Length + 1))
          }
          ).ToList();


    }
```

Method that populates the data to treeview:

```
     public List<TreeViewModel> GetRequestTreeNodesFromModel()
       {
        treeNodeViewModel = treeModel.GetRequestTreeNodes().Select(a => new TreeViewModel
        {
            Children = a.Children.Select(c => new TreeViewModel { Name = c.Name }).ToList(),
            Name = a.Name,

        }).ToList();

        return treeNodeViewModel;
    }
```

XAML

```
     <TreeView Margin="644,137,6,6" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TreeView}">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TreeViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path= Children}">
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Name}" Content="{Binding Name}" />
                    <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />-->
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
```

Comment: you dont seem to be recursively adding the Children to the TreeViewModel in the `GetRequestTreeNodesFromModel()` method

Comment: I'm calling the recursive method in that method. But I am not sure how I can do what you suggest me to do. Can you provide me a code and explanation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recursively add the `Children` from the `TreeModel` to the `TreeViewModel`.

You could make a helper function or extension method for this or just add the logic directly to your 'GetRequestTreeNodesFromModel'

Here is a example that recursively creates your `TreeViewModel` collection from the `TreeModel` collection

```
public IEnumerable<TreeViewModel> ToTreeViewModel(IEnumerable<TreeModel> treemodel)
{
    foreach (var item in treemodel)
    {
        yield return new TreeViewModel { Name = item.Name, Children = ToTreeViewModel(item.Children).ToList() };
    }
}
```

Then you can use that in your `GetRequestTreeNodesFromModel` function

```
public List<TreeViewModel> GetRequestTreeNodesFromModel()
{
    return  ToTreeViewModel(treeModel.GetRequestTreeNodes()).ToList();
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is great I will plug it in my code and test it as soon as I can ... Thank you .

Comment: This works for me. Now I am adding one root for these request nodes and I am working on adding a separate request nodes. That means now I have Parent --> request child and response child but I want to hide the parent. here is how I am adding the children to one root parent:                         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967075/wpf-how-to-hide-tree-root/16967306?noredirect=1#16967306