# WPF: How to create a relationship between Grid and tree view checkboxes

Tags: wpf, gridview, checkbox, tree

I am working on WPF application with MVVM pattern
I have a grid view from one table and a treeview from another.

I showed how I build the tree here :
[WPF: Tree view by parsing string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970273/wpf-tree-view-by-parsing-string/16973267?noredirect=1#16973267)

currently my tree has Name and list of Children attributes

now when I select an item from the grid, I want to be able to mark the tree nodes 
checkboxes as selected. and vise versa. I don't know if I need to create an id in the TreeNode model inorder to create some sort of association between tree and grid.

But I would apreciate it if someone give me a better approch to this?

I did looked over internet for better solution but I couldn't find a solution that matches what I was looking for .

Comment: Are you using MVVM design pattern in your application?

Comment: @Colin 
I added more information on my question. And provided a link that shows my tree structure.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the grid you mentioned here is a DataGrid. So you can bind the SelectedItem of the DataGrid to your view model.

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedViewModelObject}"/>
```

And then

```
public object SelectedViewModelObject
{
  get;
  set
  {
    //Get your corresponding TreeModel here and set the IsChecked property.
  }
}
```

In order to find your corresponding TreeModel, you may need some kinds of ID for association usage just as you said.

But I am wondering that whether you could set the TreeModel as the view model of your grid? In this way, the SelectedItem of the grid is the same object which is also in the tree. It means that the same TreeModel object is binded to both the tree and the grid. So you don't need any other association work here.