# TreeView: Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I am working on WPF project to display a list of path in a `TreeView`. I have propertyPaths (Ex: NetworkControl.AlternateIndexText.Value") paths have ids.

TreeModel

```
public class MessageElement
{
    private int id;
     public string Name { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
    public List<MessageElement> Children { get; set; }
    public List<MessageElement> messageElements { get; set; }

   public MessageElement()
    {
        Children = new List<MessageElement>();
        messageElements = new List<MessageElement>();
    }

    public MessageElement(int id, string name, List<MessageElement> children)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Children = children;

    }


    public MessageElement(int id, string path)
    {

        this.ID = id;
        this.path = path;

    }
}
```

moq some data

```
   public List<MessageElement> GetRequestTreeNodes()
    {

        messageElements.Add(new MessageElement(1, "NetworkControl.AlternateIndexText.Value"));
        messageElements.Add(new MessageElement(2, "NetworkControl.AddressData.DestinationID"));
        messageElements.Add(new MessageElement(2, "NetworkControl.AddressData.MessageOriginatorID.Value"));


        messageElements.Add(new MessageElement(3, "VehicleSummary.VehicleIdentification.IdentificationID.Value"));
        messageElements.Add(new MessageElement(3, "TitleSummary.JurisdictionTitlingKeyText.Value"));
        messageElements.Add(new MessageElement(1, "VehicleSummary.VehicleIdentification.IdentificationID.Value"));



        return messageElements;
```

}

recursively create tree:

```
   public List<MessageElement> BuildTree(IEnumerable<MessageElement> messageElements)
    {

        return (
          from element in messageElements           // Ex:(1, "NetworkControl.AlternateIndexText.Value")
          let elementId = element.id                       // get id from message element
          let splitPath = element.path.Split('.')   // get path from  message element
          group element by element.path.Split('.')[0] into pathElementGroup

          select new MessageElement(ID, path)
          {
             ID = elementId,  ??                                 // id of each path  Ex: 1 => "NetworkControl.AlternateIndexText.Value"
              Name = pathElementGroup.Key,             //name of each tree node to be displayed on tree
              Children = BuildTree(                    //create child from the propertyPath
                 (from propertyPathElement in pathElementGroup
                  where propertyPathElement.path.Length > pathElementGroup.Key.Length + 1
                  select new MessageElement())
                 .ToList<MessageElement>())
          }
          );

    }


    }
```

How can I remove this exception so that i can build my tree recursively ?

Comment: Could you list the full message of the exception and ideally also a stack trace?

Comment: @Rob                                                               The best overloaded method match for 'MessageElement.BuildTree(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MetaDataMappingUtility.MetaDataUI.MessageElement>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: What is the data type of "pathElementGroup" ?

Comment: @Rakesh  IGrouping<string,MessageElement>

Comment: @Rakesh I updated the BuildTree method with your suggestion... now I am passing in (IEnumerable<MessageElement> messageElements) but I still have problem..How can I get the ids related to each path? Ex: 1, "NetworkControl.AlternateIndexText.Value"

Comment: Can you explain how tree should look for input provided by "GetRequestTreeNodes" method?

Comment: It should have the image provided in the link below. initially when I start working one the tree what I was doing was creating node from path and give a name. But Now I want to uniquely identify each path in order to create a relationship with another control i have, which is a grid.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970273/wpf-tree-view-by-parsing-string?noredirect=1#comment24516314_16970273

Comment: I've updated the answer, see if this helps your cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code, you need to create MessageElement as you are projecting your data to Build List function which accepts `List<MessageElement >`

On a side note, why are you not accepting `IEnumerable<MessageElement>` as input parameter to BuildList method?

```
var result = BuildTree(0, GetRequestTreeNodes());

 public List<MessageElement> BuildTree(int depth, List<MessageElement> messageElements)
        {
            if (messageElements == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return (
                  from element in BuildGrouping(depth, messageElements)           // Ex:(1, "NetworkControl.AlternateIndexText.Value")
                  let elementId = element.Key                      // get id from message element

                  select new MessageElement()
                  {
                      ID = depth,                                  // id of each path  Ex: 1 => "NetworkControl.AlternateIndexText.Value"
                      Name = element.Key,             //name of each tree node to be displayed on tree
                      Children = BuildTree(depth +1,                    //create child from the propertyPath
                        element.ToList<MessageElement>())
                  }
                  ).ToList<MessageElement>();

        }

        public IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, MessageElement>> BuildGrouping(int depth, List<MessageElement> messageElements)
        {
            string key = string.Empty;
            if (messageElements != null && messageElements.Count > 0)
            {
                string[] splits = messageElements[0].path.Split('.');
                if (splits.Length > depth)
                {
                    key = splits[depth];
                }
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
            {
                return new List<IGrouping<string, MessageElement>>();
            }

            return from element in messageElements group element by element.path.Split('.')[depth];
        }
```

Comment: Thank you let me try this. I would use IEnumerable if that makes things easier when i start this work I tried to work on what i thought was easier. Would be nice if you can explain to me the benefit of replacing with that

Comment: LINQ is syntactic sugar based on generic IEnumerable<T> interface, check details here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397947.aspx

Comment: In my ViewModel I am doing this am getting null reference exception after I test your code. I updated my original post. Can you look at that?

Comment: ...I think there is a problem in the code. The idea was to reserve each id that is assigned to each path..EX. 1, "NetworkControl.AlternateIndexText.Value" or 2, "NetworkControl.AddressData.DestinationID" and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Because a ***LINQ*** query returns some **IEnumerable<T>**, not a **List<T>**, so you have to apply **ToList**:

```
    BuildTree(                    //create child from the propertyPath
    (from propertyPathElement in pathElementGroup
    where propertyPathElement.path.Length > pathElementGroup.Key.Length + 1
    select propertyPathElement.path.Substring(pathElementGroup.Key.Length + 1)).ToList())
          }
```

Comment: I am getting three exceptions                                             cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MetaDataMappingUtility.MetaDataUI.MessageElement>'

The name 'elementId' does not exist in the current context 

The best overloaded method match for 'MessageElement.BuildTree(System.Collections.Generic.List<MetaDataMappingUtility.MetaDataUI.MessageElement>)' has some invalid arguments    I am also new to linq .. would be great if you show me a full code with explanation

Comment: Because you "select propertyPathElement.path.Substring(pathElementGroup.Key.Length + 1)" so it will produce a IEnumerable<string>

Comment: This seems to resolve the cast issue but how can I extract each id/ path?                                                        Children = BuildTree(                    //create child from the propertyPath
                     (from propertyPathElement in pathElementGroup
                      where propertyPathElement.path.Length > pathElementGroup.Key.Length + 1
                      select new MessageElement()).ToList<MessageElement>())